# Increase in query execution time after generating statistics for the target table (Oracle DB)

Tags: oracle, performance, optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have created a new table (tmp_requests_5) in the database and populate it with 290k rows of test data. Right after that, I execute the following query:

```
select * 
from tmp_requests_5 r 
join request_statuses rs on ( rs.id = r.status_id ) 
left join users u on ( u.id = r.created_user_id )
left join executors e on ( e.id = r.executor_id )
order by r.id desc
```

It runs in 0.045 seconds with the following execution plan:

[Execution plan before generating statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHBPE.jpg)

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                     |   361K|    10G|  1039K  (1)| 00:00:41 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                  |                     |   361K|    10G|  1039K  (1)| 00:00:41 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER           |                     |   361K|    10G|   678K  (1)| 00:00:27 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |                     |   361K|    10G|   335K  (1)| 00:00:14 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TMP_REQUESTS_5      |   361K|    10G|   622   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      INDEX FULL SCAN DESCENDING| TMP_REQUESTS_5_PK   |   361K|       |   622   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| USERS               |     1 |   119 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | USERS_PK            |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | EXECUTORS           |     1 |    50 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | EXECUTORS_PK        |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | REQUEST_STATUSES    |     1 |    69 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | REQUEST_STATUSES_PK |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   4 - filter(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("R"."DESCRIPTION" /*+ LOB_BY_VALUE */ ) AND 
              INTERNAL_FUNCTION("R"."RESOLUTION" /*+ LOB_BY_VALUE */ ) AND 
              INTERNAL_FUNCTION("R"."RESPONSE_TO_APPLICANT" /*+ LOB_BY_VALUE */ ))
   7 - access("U"."ID"(+)="R"."CREATED_USER_ID")
   8 - filter(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("E"."RESPONSIBILITY_AREA" /*+ LOB_BY_VALUE */ ))
   9 - access("E"."ID"(+)="R"."EXECUTOR_ID")
  11 - access("RS"."ID"="R"."STATUS_ID")
```

But after statistics are generated for the new table, the same query runs much slower (10 seconds), although the cost is reduced. Here is the execution plan after generating statistics:

[Execution plan after generating statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M9VI.jpg)

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation               | Name             | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |                  |   289K|   390M|       |   100K  (1)| 00:00:04 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY          |                  |   289K|   390M|   453M|   100K  (1)| 00:00:04 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER |                  |   289K|   390M|       | 14375   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL    | USERS            |    14 |  1666 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER|                  |   289K|   357M|       | 14371   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL   | EXECUTORS        |     4 |   200 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     HASH JOIN           |                  |   289K|   343M|       | 14367   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL  | REQUEST_STATUSES |     5 |   345 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL  | TMP_REQUESTS_5   |   289K|   324M|       | 14363   (1)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("U"."ID"(+)="R"."CREATED_USER_ID")
   4 - access("E"."ID"(+)="R"."EXECUTOR_ID")
   5 - filter(INTERNAL_FUNCTION( /*+ LVC_LAZY_LOAD */ "E"."RESPONSIBILITY_AREA" /*+ 
              LOB_BY_VALUE */ ))
   6 - access("RS"."ID"="R"."STATUS_ID")
   8 - filter(INTERNAL_FUNCTION( /*+ LVC_LAZY_LOAD */ "R"."DESCRIPTION" /*+ LOB_BY_VALUE */ 
              ) AND INTERNAL_FUNCTION( /*+ LVC_LAZY_LOAD */ "R"."RESOLUTION" /*+ LOB_BY_VALUE */ ) AND 
              INTERNAL_FUNCTION( /*+ LVC_LAZY_LOAD */ "R"."RESPONSE_TO_APPLICANT" /*+ LOB_BY_VALUE */ ))
```

I would like the execution plan to remain the same as before the statistics were generated, since it takes much less time. I've tried using optimizer hints, but have not been successful.

Is it possible to specify for the database the execution plan for this query as it was originally, before generating statistics for this table? If so, how can this be done and will there be any negative effects from this? I will be grateful for any help.

---

Database version: Oracle 19с standatrd edition

Comment: "It runs in X seconds ..." - what do you mean by runs? The first N rows would be delivered musch faster with nested loops and indexes because nested loops can pipeline its output to the upstream operators, while hash join have to buils a hash for the left table to produce its output. Did you try to use `create table as select` to compare both these queries? Or something that will fetch all rows from the cursor

Comment: @astentx "what do you mean by runs?" - I'm running this query in Oracle SQL Developer. It returns the first 50 rows of the sample by default. This works for me, since I plan to use this query for a selection with a pagination of 50 records.
"...compare both these queries..." - there is only one query. I have run it twice. The first time immediately after creating the table and entering test data into it. The second time after the database generates statistics for this table.

Comment: @astentx As far as I understand, after the formation of statistics, the database optimizer changes the execution plan.
I've realized that nested loops are better for fetching a small number of records, now I'm trying to give a hint to the optimizer to use them. In the documentation I found a hint "use_nl(<table_name >)" - which does this, but so far it only works for left joins.

Comment: You may also try `/*+FIRST_ROWS*/` hint to tell the database about your intent without other hints. Or `/*+USE_NL_WITH_INDEX*/`